# Multiplying prices with one in cent is the same as them all added

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible for all prices out of a list of prices (in Euro/Dollar) multiplied together, with one of them in cent however, to amount to the same total of 20.18€ as all of them added together? (multiplying them and having one price in cent cancel out)

Example:

**1€+2.50€+0.5€= 4€**

**1€*2.50€*50ct= 125€**

I can't figure out how to compile such a list where no rounding is necessary.

I tried to calculate the prices presuming there are only two articles:

**a+b = 20.18**

**a*100b = 20.18**

However, solved the solution is not possible with actual money (as in the amount is not even but irrational).

Any ideas?
Does it matter that I presumed there are only two articles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well the solution to $x^2=8$ is also irrational, but the solution to $x^3=8$ isn't. The fact that the solution is irrational with two variables doesn't necessarily say anything about the solution in three variables.

Comment: So essentially the problem is finding numbers $x_0, x_1, x_2$ etc so that
$$
x_0 + x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 100 x_1 \times x_2 \times \ldots \times x_n
$$
Indeed a good idea would be to start with two numbers and then work your way up. However, it's clear that you can only use relatively small numbers because multiplying by a large number has a much larger effect than adding a large number.

Comment: Actually, you can build a list by starting with any (two or more) numbers whose product and sum is a whole number, and then adding $1$'s to the list until both sides of the equation are equal. Adding 1 increases the left-hand side but does nothing to the right-hand side.

Comment: Fun fact: it's never going to work with more than $21$ numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let me say: I really, really don't like fractions, *especially* not when their denominator has to divide $100$. So, let's rewrite the equations to something with nice, whole numbers:

\begin{align}
\frac{x_1}{100}+\frac{x_2}{100}+\cdots+\frac{x_k}{100}&=20.18\\
100\cdot\frac{x_1}{100}\cdot\frac{x_2}{100}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{x_k}{100}&=20.18\\
\end{align}

Where all $x_i$s are positive integers. Now we can rewrite this to

\begin{align}
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k&=2018\\
x_1x_2\cdots x_k&=2018\cdot100^{k-2}\\
\end{align}

---

So, the equation with the product is actually fairly useful now. We need the product of all $x_i$s to be $2018\cdot 100^{k-2}$, which factorizes as $2^{2k-3}5^{2k-4}\cdot1009$. That means at least one of the numbers must have a factor $1009$. If it is not $1009$ itself, it is at least $2\cdot1009=2018$; however, with the sum of all $x_i$s being $2018$, and all $x_i$s being positive, this is never going to work. So, one of the numbers we need is $1009$; let's say $x_k=1009$. The equations becomes
\begin{align}
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{k-1}&=1009\\
x_1x_2\cdots x_{k-1}&=2^{2k-3}5^{2k-4}\\
\end{align}

---

To get a feel for the problem we've turned this into, let's set some values for $k$. We need $k$ to be at least $2$, so let's start there.

**Case 1: $k=2$**. Now, $x_1=1009$ and $x_1=2$. That's *very* impossible.

**Case 2: $k=3$**. We find $x_1+x_2=1009$ and $x_1x_2=2^35^2$. Again, impossible. Whatever $x_i$s we choose, if the product is $2^35^2=200$, then the sum is never going to be as much as $1009$.

**Case 3: $k=4$**. This time, $x_1+x_2+x_3=1009$ and $x_1x_2x_3=2^55^4$. This might be possible; so, let's try something. We want the sum to get close to $1009$, so let's pick $x_3=1000$. Then we need $x_1+x_2=9$ and $x_1x_2=2^2\cdot5$. Yes. YES. You see it? $x_1=4$, and $x_2=5$. We've found a solution!

---

So, we've found $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(4,5,1000,1009)$. This translate to the following prices:

- €0.04 (4ct)
- €0.05
- €10,-
- €10.09

And indeed, their sum is €20.18, and their product, one being in cents, is (4ct)*(€0.05)*(€10)*(€10.09) which also is €20.18.

*(Disclaimer: I don't actually dislike fractions, I just like integers more :D)*